# Implementing an Animated Menu Background in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have recently been trying to fine tune my Android game before release to make it much more appealing to users.  I have noticed a simple trend in various successful games in that most of them seem to have animated backgrounds integrated with their menus.  Specifically, I mean having, say, the leaves on some trees waving in the wind, or some clouds moving across the screen behind the buttons to start new games.

### My Question

What is an efficient way to implement such behavior?  I have pursued many avenues already but they all leave me questioning the approach I am taking because they seem to require so much overhead.

### What I have Tried So Far

- Setting the background resource ( `android:background="animation.xml"`) to an animation file that then links to the 30 or so frames.

The problem I am having with this approach is that it seems to be a huge waste of space to have 30 .png files that have the same resolution as the screen the device is running on packaged with my game.  I should be able to animate them directly, right?

- Using yet another `SurfaceView` to render the screen and simply animate it by hard coding location information, and simply overlay the buttons.

The problem here is that I have to work with the intricacies of stopping one thread, starting another (the game thread), and making sure that when they are restarted (the user presses BACK), that the thread had already closed.  This seems like quite a bit of overhead to implement just to animate a menu screen.

### What I Have Considered

I have considered the idea of using 'tween animations to move view skinned with my .png's across the screen.  However, this seems like a really "hacky" approach and I would prefer if I could avoid such a maneuver.

---

Has anyone had any difficulties with this in the past?  What have been your respective approaches?  I could always just launch the game as is, but I would really like to make it as appealing as possible.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!